# Eclipse Luna vs Kepler

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I am currently using 64 bits Kepler with IBM Websphere Developer Tools and it is running very slow. The eclipse process regularly uses 800M - 1.2G and it freezes my computer from time to time (waiting for GC, I guess).

I am considering upgrade it to Luna.
My question is: Will Luna use less memory? Will I get some performance improvements after upgrade?

If anyone have similar experience, please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have enough memory?  Does the Eclipse process need more memory allocated (in the startup configuration file)?

Comment: My PC has sufficient memory and I have tweaked the eclipse.ini file (increasing -xmx, etc). From my experience, creating a new workspace will improve performance for a few days, but after that it will be back to the same snail pace.

Comment: This sounds more like a plugin which does a lot of work on a lot of data.  As plain eclipse has worked fine for me, I would suspect the websphere tools. Do you have IBM support - this might be a bug in their code.

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem with websphere tool.

Comment: I almost always download Eclipse Classic and then install very minimal absolutely required plugins.  Never had such issues.  Practically speaking, upgrading Eclipse didn't yield any performance improvements, but in most cases made it even worser.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse for a few years manly with PDT and some other Web-Development-Plugins (maybe first was Europa).

Since Juno or Kepler the performance and stability improves a lot. So just update when your plugin-set allows it.

Btw. since june '15 is Mars out - and for me it's really stable.